# Was 360 considered a magic number, possibly?

Tags: ancient-greece, number-theory

The number $360$ as the number of units into which the circle is divided has [some nice properties](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/origin-of-360-degrees):

- it has as many divisors as a number of its size can have
- it's nearly the number of days per year

But none of these properties is really "magic", so the number $360$ [isn't really distinguished mathematically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142735/why-is-a-full-turn-of-the-circle-360-why-not-any-other-number) and may have been chosen mainly for practical and logistic reasons.

I wonder if there is evidence that the number $360$ has been seen as a somehow "magic" number by ancient mathematicians. For example, it is the number that combines the first three natural numbers $1,2,3$ with the first three prime numbers $2,3,5$:

$$360 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1$$

Note, that the number $12$ (which happens to be the number of months per year) is the number that combines the first two natural numbers $1,2$ with the first two prime numbers $2,3$:

$$12 = 2^2 \cdot 3^1$$

And $2$ (the number of halves of the year) is just

$$2 = 2^1$$

Note, that OEIS knows the sequence $2,12,360$ under the name of [Chernoff sequence](https://oeis.org/A006939) but hasn't got a lot to tell about it.

Comment: See Roland Laroche, [Popular Symbolic-Mystical Numbers in Antiquity (1995)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41541653); but $360$ is not listed there.

Comment: Might want to blame it on the Sumerians  (and lots of things divide nicely in base-60)

Comment: And the number of months in the year was 10 until one of the Caesars fluffed his own self-importance.

Comment: I do not know about magic or ancients, but as far as mathematical properties 360 is one of [Ramanujan's highly abundant numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_abundant_number), i.e. the sum of its divisors is greater than that of any smaller number.  Then again, highly abundant numbers are not exactly rare. As with 12, the reasons for adopting 360 likely came from astronomy, not "magic", see [Was there a very early culture that's number system was 12-based, like ours is 10-based?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2881/55)